# End of Line on Windows cmd

Tags: c++, cmd

I have a

while(cin >> string)

loop in which I want the user to input a string. However, I do not know how to end the input. I know on *nix machines for bash shell, I can use ctrl-D. But this does not seem to work on cmd.exe for Windows...

Any tips?

[Edit] This is on C++

Comment: I think you mean "end of file", not "end of line"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Windows equivalent of `Ctrl+D` is `Ctrl+Z Enter`.

Answer (score 2):

The end of file character is ctrl-Z in windows